# Exec Format Error When Starting .NET 6.0 Linux Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, redhat

I have a .NET 6.0 minimal api that i have configured in my program.cs to run as a systemd service as seen below

```
            if (Debugger.IsAttached == false)
            {
                if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
                {
                    builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
                    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        int port = 1000;
                        int.TryParse(config.GetValue<string>("MicroServicePort"), out port);
                        serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(port, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(config.GetValue<string>("WindowsCertificatePath"));
                        });

                    });
                }
                if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
                {
                    builder.Host.UseSystemd();
                    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        int port = 1000;
                        int.TryParse(config.GetValue<string>("MicroServicePort"), out port);
                        serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(port, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(config.GetValue<string>("LinuxCertificatePath"), config.GetValue<string>("CertificatePassword"));
                        });

                    });
                }
            }
```

I have published this service using the following Visual Studio profile

[image]

I did a self contained deployment thus I haven't installed the .NET runtime on the target linux server. As for the linux server, the `uname -m` command prints
`x86_64` and the `uname -a` command prints:

Linux LoadTesting 4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 29 08:54:30 EDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I then moved the published files to the linux (RedHat) server using WinSCP.

Below is the .service configuration file that i have put in /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=WebAPI
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
User=johndoe
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/Microservices/LinuxServices/WebAPI/Publish/WebAPI.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And finally the error that i am noting when i check the service logs by  `journalctl | grep WebAPI` is:

```
Feb 03 02:39:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: Stopped WebAPI.
Feb 03 02:39:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: Started WebAPI.
Feb 03 02:39:42 LoadTesting systemd[14975]: WebAPI.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Feb 03 02:39:42 LoadTesting systemd[14975]: WebAPI.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/Microservices/LinuxServices/WebAPI/Publish/WebAPI.dll: Exec format error
Feb 03 02:39:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: WebAPI.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 03 02:39:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: WebAPI.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 03 02:40:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: WebAPI.service: Service RestartSec=1min expired, scheduling restart.
Feb 03 02:40:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: WebAPI.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 47.
Feb 03 02:40:42 LoadTesting systemd[1]: Stopped WebAPI.
```

I am very new to deploying services/APIs to linux so if there is a obvious config that i ought to already have done, feel free to bring it up.

Comment: A DLL is a *library* and can't be executed, similar to an `.so` library on Linux. The folder probably contains a `WebAPI.exe` file. That's the actual executable

Comment: Try running your application directly *before* trying to start it as a service. There may be other problems preventing the application from starting up, eg incorrect or missing settings. It's easier to test this from the command line that checking a service log

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when i deploy as a windows service, i can see that a .exe file is generated and when looking at it from the file explorer the Type column indicates it is an Application. However when published as a linux service, the file exists but has a blank Type. What extension should i put when defining the ExecStart in my .services file?

Comment: The extension doesn't matter on Linux. As long as the file is marked executable, Linux will try to execute it. That's how shell or Python scripts can be executed directly.  `ExecStart` needs the actual path to the executable file. Again, try to execute the file from the command line first. You can't make anything run as a service if it can't even run from the command line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have done as you have said by running ```./WebAPI``` I can now see the following error: ```Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Please install libicu using your package manager and try again.```  i will follow the error's suggestion and update on whether it worked in a few hours.

Comment: That means the `libicu` library is missing from the Linux distribution. That's not part of the .NET Core runtime itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok so i set the <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization> tag in my .csproj as suggested here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization and i was able to run it successfully using  ```./WebAPI``` (i was able to reach my API over the internet and see its logs). However, when i run the service, it runs with no logs in the ```jounalctl``` and it's status stays as ```running``` but the WebApi is unreachable and it isn't logging anything.